# Adding classes when anchor hits the topscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I am working on a dynamic one-pager website, bootstrap based, where animations shows up depending of the section scrolled.

Actually, I have this, which works great, but not really behaving the way I'd wish. This code adds a `display:block` class to an element that was `display:none` when you hover the proper section :

```
<script>
 $(function() {
  $('#datpage1').hover(function() {
    // on mousehover, show the hidden div
    $('.helloitsme').css('display', 'block');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, hide the div
    $('.helloitsme').css('display', 'none');
  });
});
</script>
```

This way, when the user scrolls and is hovering the section, some fixed divs appears over the site content showing hints.

Here is the CSS of one of the elements:

```
.helloitsme {
    display: none;
}
.helloitsme img {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

My concern with this solution is that it's not working on mobile devices, and that the animation depends on the users mousehover.

So I am trying to find a jQuery way to make div appears when the section anchors hits the top screen, so it could more precisely work, on mobile devices too.

I came up with this technique :

```
<script>
var fl = $("#datpage1").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
     if(this.scrollTop() > fl) {
       $('.helloitsme').css('display', 'block');
     }, function() {
       // on mouseout, reset the background colour
       $('.helloitsme').css('display', 'none');
    });
});
</script>
```

but can't manage to make it work.. think it might be related to this techniques syntax, which I'm trying to figure out.

If anyone have a tip, trick or else, feel free :)
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something simulates your issue [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/96nevnsq/), basically any of the `div.section`'s children which has a class of `.hidden` won't be shown until the parent section's top reaches top of the view, if it reached then we show this hidden element.

Also for the first `div.section` we need to show its `.hidden` children because it is already in the view instead of showing a blank screen until the scroll events get fired.

**JS:**

```
var $scroll, $top, $id, $sections = $('.section');

// Shows the hidden children of the first section...
//since it's already hit the top of the view
$sections.first().children('.hidden').css({'display':'block'});
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    $scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $sections.each(function(){
        $th = $(this);
        $top = $th.position().top;
        $id = $th.attr('id');

        // If this section's top reached the top of the view..
        // show its hidden children
        if($top < $scroll){
            $th.children('.hidden').css({'display':'block'});
        }      
    });
});
```

---

**CSS:**

```
.section{
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    display:block;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #CCC;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:4em;
    color:white;
}
.section p{
    font-size:18pt;
    font-style:italic;
}
.section img{
    margin:0 auto;
    border:4px white solid;
}
.section .hidden{
    display:none;
}
.orange{ background-color:orange; }
.green{ background-color:#009900; }
.blue{ background-color:navy; }
.red{ background-color:#990000; }
```

---

**HTML:**

```
<div class="section orange">
    A
    <p class="hidden">I'm hidden until this section hits the top</p>
    <img class="hidden" src="//placehold.it/350x150?text=Image A">
</div>
<div class="section green">
    B
    <p class="hidden">I'm hidden until this section's top hits the top</p>
    <img class="hidden" src="//placehold.it/350x150?text=Image B">
</div>
<div class="section blue">
    C
    <p class="hidden">I'm hidden until this section's top hits the top</p>
    <img class="hidden" src="//placehold.it/350x150?text=Image C">
</div>
<div class="section red">
    D
    <p class="hidden">I'm hidden until this section's top hits the top</p>
    <img class="hidden" src="//placehold.it/350x150?text=Image D">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, exactly the behaviour I am looking for @Mi-Creativity, thank you. Strange thing is that I can't manage to make it work on the actual site, not even on an empty sheet, on localhost, jQuery library 1.11.3.. do you have an idea?

Comment: Weird, it should work, it is working on **CodePen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbPxxZ, **LiveWeave:**  http://liveweave.com/61iOJR, and **Plunker:**  http://plnkr.co/edit/Hok0fmTIi40VO9XM6SWh?p=preview , all these as well as locally and **JS Fiddle**

Comment: I found out it was something overriding in the bootstrap.css... so when I unlink this stylesheet, everything works. I'll try to figure this out. Infinite thanks again ! And if you have an idea for that CSS override thing, feel free :)

Comment: Actually this is one of the reason I don't like Frameworks for, but try to rename the classes name make them unique with some weird prefix or so in order not to have similar class names maybe it'll work, like `.abc-section`, `.abc-hidden` and so on

Comment: Yep, did the thing :) Thanks again !